# Find the value of $a + b + c + d$ where they must be positive integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Amy has four **positive** integers **$\mathbf{a, b, c,}$ and $\mathbf{d}$.**

After computing the values of $a + b$, $a + c$, $a + d$, $b + c$, $b + d$, and $c + d$, she found four of these
values were **$\mathbf{41, 70, 82,}$ and $\mathbf{98}$**.

Find the value of $\mathbf{a + b + c + d}$.

Note: I found out that it can not be $2(a+b+c+d)$ since the sum of $41$, $70$, $82$ and $98$ is odd ($291$). But I am stuck in finding $a+b+c+d$. I have tried different combinations, but it still doesn't work as they must be positive integers (no decimals). It is very hard to find them one by one.

I have spent a day solving this problem already, please help! Lots and lots of thanks.

Comment: You have computed the sum, but how is it related to $a, b, c, d$?

Comment: The sum of 41, 70, 82, and 98 can either be

a+ 2b+ 2c+ 2d
b+ 2a+ 2c+ 2d
c+ 2a+ 2b+ 2d
d+ 2a+ 2b+ 2c (I just added it :D) Thanks for reminding

Comment: **Hint.** By the pigeonhole property, some pair of those sums must sum to $a+b+c+d$. That means the only possible values of $a+b+c+d$ are $111, 123, 139, 152, 168, 180$. Since those values are all distinct, it cannot be two separate pairs of numbers. Does that help?

Comment: One of the numbers must be represented three times, and one of them must be represented only once. W.l.o.g., the sums must be $a+b, a+c, a+d, c+d$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your hint. I can now fully understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about the parities of the four integers, the only possibility is that you have three even and an odd, or three odd and an even (for instance if two were even and two odd there would only be two even totals and you are given three). In both these two cases, the even totals come from the sums in pairs of the three integers with the same parity, so you can just take $a+b=70$, $b+c=82$ and $c+a=98$: this gives (just algebra): $a=27$, $b=43$, $c=55$. Then the sum of 41 can only come from $d=14$, as $43$ and $55$ are larger than $41$. Hence $a+b+c+d=139$.

Comment: Thank you. That is a simple and detailed explanation for beginners - I can now fully understand it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

As the OP (original poster) indicated, the $(4)$ partial sums, having an odd total, can not represent $2(a+b+c+d).$

Therefore, you can assume, without loss of generality that

$(3)$ of the $(4)$ sums are $(a+b), (a+c), (a+d).$

You can also assume, without loss of generality, that $b \leq c \leq d.$

So, $(a+b), (a+c), (a+d),$ must **respectively** equal one of the following:

- $41,70,82, ~\implies ~b = c - 29, ~d = c + 12 \implies $
  $3a + 3c - 17 = 193 \implies a + c = 70.$
- $41,70,98 ~\implies ~b = c - 29, ~d = c + 28 \implies $
  $3a + 3c - 1 = 209 ~\implies a + c = 70.$
- $41,82,98 ~\implies ~b = c - 41, ~d = c + 16 \implies $
  $3a + 3c - 25 = 221 \implies a + c = 82.$
- $70,82,98 ~\implies ~b = c - 12, ~d = c + 16 \implies $
  $3a + 3c + 4 = 250 \implies a + c = 82.$

---

At this point, my suspicion is that each of the $4$ cases that does not lead to a contradiction will lead to the same answer.  However, I will explore each of them, one at a time.

The first case, represents that $(a+c) = 70$ and that $(98)$ is the partial sum that does not involve $(a)$.  So, either $(98)$ involves $(b)$ or it doesn't.  $(98)$ can not represent either $(b+c) = 2c - 29$ or $(b+d) = 2c - 17.$

Therefore, following up on the first case, you have that
$(98) = (c + d) = 2c + 12 \implies (a,b,c,d) = (27,14,43,55)$.

---

Similarly, in the second case, if the partial sum that does not involve $(a)$, $(82)$, involves $(b)$ then you end up with $(2c)$ equaling an odd integer.

So, you have that $c+d = (2c + 28) = 82 \implies 
c = 27.$  This yields a contradiction, because in the 2nd case, it is assumed that $b = c - 29.$

---

Similarly, in the third case, if the partial sum that does not involve $(a)$, $(70)$, involves $(b)$ then you end up with $(2c)$ equaling an odd integer.

So, you have that $c+d = (2c + 16) = 70 \implies c = 27.$ 
This yields a contradiction, because it is assumed here that $b = c - 41.$

---

In the fourth case, the partial sum that does not involve $(a)$ is $(41)$.  This is immediately seen to be impossible, because in the fourth case, $b,c,d$ all have the same odd/even parity.  So, none of $~(b+c),~(b+d), ~(c+d),~$ can have an odd sum.

---

Therefore, the case 1 solution is unique.